# Blank xslt transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

I am transforming the following xml but its blank.

I am looking to add testcase to the body and make it h1. I am very confused.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuite errors="1" failures="0" name="TestDemo-20150928232552" tests="1" time="11.405">
    <properties/>
    <system-out>
<![CDATA[]]>    </system-out>
    <system-err>
<![CDATA[]]>    </system-err>
    <testcase classname="TestDemo" name="test_contactForm" time="11.405">
        <error message="Message: Unable to find element with xpath '//select[@name='tosh']/option[@value='26 - 50']'
Screenshot: available via screen
" type="NoSuchElementException">
<![CDATA[Traceback (most recent call last):
NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to find element with xpath '//select[@name='tosh']/option[@value='26 - 50']'    
]]>     </error>
    </testcase>
</testsuite>
```

Help please. Any tips or advice is greatly appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>
                    <xsl:value-of select="testcase"/>
                </title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="body"/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="testcase">
        <h1><xsl:value-of select="."/></h1>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="error">
        <p><xsl:apply-templates/></p>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part:

```
<title>
    <xsl:value-of select="testcase"/>
</title>
```

returns an empty `title` element, because you are in the context of the `/` root node, and `testcase` is not a child of the `/` root node. You need to do:

```
<title>
    <xsl:value-of select="testsuite/testcase"/>
</title>
```

if you want the `title` to contain all the text contents of `testcase` (somehow I doubt you really want that).

This part:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="body"/>
```

doesn't do anything, because there's no `body` element anywhere in your XML. It should probably be just:

```
<xsl:apply-templates/>
```

And this template doesn't do anything, because it is never applied:

```
<xsl:template match="error">
    <p><xsl:apply-templates/></p>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.